# Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: html, django

I recevied an error when I request any page in the blog project I am working on, and I have no idea what is going wrong. Please help!

**views.py**

```
    def post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post=post)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-detail", kwargs={
                'id': post.id
            }))

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

here is the **model.py**:

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #thumbanail = models.ImageField()
    #comment_count = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    #view_count = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })


    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post-update', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })


    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('post-delete', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comments.all().order_by('-timestamp')


    @property
    def comment_count(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=self).count()


    @property
    def view_count(self):
        return PostView.objects.filter(post=self).count()
```

This is the I am receiving:

FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'comment_count' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, categories, comments, content, featured, id, overview, postview, timestamp, title
*

Comment: Can you please share the *full* traceback? You likely make a query that somehow uses the old `comment_count` field.

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Comment: Is it because you've commented out `comment_count` field in **models.py**?

Comment: I don't think so. I removed the hashtag but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Like Hisahm__Pak said

remove #comment_count = models.IntegerField(default= 0)

```
  comment_count = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
```

then save and make migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

then run the server

```
python manage.py runserver
```